# Colorize line number in grep

Tags: grep, colors

Is there a way to colorize line numbers when using `grep` with the `-n` option?

For example, 
`echo "hello" | grep -n lo`
outputs

`1:hello`

where `lo` is colorized in red (being the match). Can I configure grep to colorize the line number, i.e. the `1:` portion? Are there specific shells/terminals that allow that?

Comment: `grep --color -n lo` should do it.

Comment: If you don't see the line number colorized (it should be olive green by default), check whether you have a `GREP_COLOR` or `GREP_COLORS` environment variable that's overriding the default color choices.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at [***GREP_COLORS***](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html), you will find color for `l`ine-`n`umber is defined by `ln` and another `fn` for `f`ile-`n`ame colorize; these accept 3 sets ***X***;***Y***;***Z*** of colors with below format:

- ***`X`*** can set to one of these (represent the Display Attributes):

  0 Reset all attributes

  1 Bright

  2 Dim

  4 Underscore

  5 Blink

  7 Reverse

  8 Hidden
- ***`Y`*** can set to one of these (represent the Foreground Colors):

  30 Black

  31 Red

  32 Green

  33 Yellow

  34 Blue

  35 Magenta

  36 Cyan

  37 White
- ***`Z`*** can set to one of these (represent the Background Colors):

  40 Black

  41 Red

  42 Green

  43 Yellow

  44 Blue

  45 Magenta

  46 Cyan

  47 White

So to colorize the line-number set `ln` to in this format `ln=X;Y;Z` (Choose ***X*** &***Y*** &***Z*** colors one from the above list); "note that your Terminal should support the ANSI Colors":

```
GREP_COLORS='ln=5;30;43' \grep -n --color 'pattern'
```

test with `seq 10 |GREP_COLORS='ln=5;30;43:fn=0' \grep --color -nH .` (noticed that line-numbers blinking in yellow background and black foreground color? and we reset the `fn` for file-name color); yes, multiple color options can separate with a colon.

see also [How to make grep to blink the matched pattern?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/613959/72456) which is my favorite.

Comment: I can't get it to work on Mac :(

Answer (score 0):

Does `grep "string" --color=always filename` as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981601/colorized-grep-viewing-the-entire-file-with-highlighted-matches) work for you?

Comment: this highlight matched pattern itself not the _line-numbers_ as OP stated