# How to make grep to blink the matched pattern?

Tags: grep, colors

What color-schemas should I set to grep's *GREP_COLORS* ENV-Variable to enable the blinking mode on matched pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GREP_COLORS='mt=X;Y;Z' grep --color 'pattern' infile`

- ***`X`*** can set to one of these (represent the Display Attributes):
  0 Reset all attributes
  1 Bright
  2 Dim
  4 Underscore 
  **5 Blink**
  7 Reverse
  8 Hidden
- ***`Y`*** can set to one of these (represent the Foreground Colors):
  30 Black
  31 Red
  32 Green
  33 Yellow
  34 Blue
  35 Magenta
  36 Cyan
  37 White
- ***`Z`*** can set to one of these (represent the Background Colors):
  40 Black
  41 Red
  42 Green
  43 Yellow
  44 Blue
  45 Magenta
  46 Cyan
  47 White

So to blinking the pattern set `mt` (Matched-Text) to: `mt=5;Y;Z` (Choose ***Y*** &***Z*** colors one from the above list); "note that your Terminal should support the ANSI Colors":

```
GREP_COLORS='mt=5;30;43' grep --color 'pattern' infile
```

see [***GREP_COLORS***](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Environment-Variables.html) options for more.

Comment: My terminal didn't want to blink, but in my tests I got 3 <=> italic and 9 <=> strikethrough.

Comment: @A.B none of these affect blinking either? `echo -e "\033[31;1;5mHello\033[0m"` or `echo -e "\033[31;1;6mHello\033[0m"`

Comment: Finally found that good ol' xterm does blink (`tput blink` works only in this one.). Note of my newer terminal emulators do.

Comment: Any idea why the 3 different colors don't work on mac?

Comment: @SridharSarnobat would you mind to open a new question and describe in better way of how it doesn't work? what is your terminal `echo $TERM`? it doesn't work in all terminals

Comment: I’ll post a new question if I feel motivated enough. I’m resigned to it not working (I have other coloring working, and the TERM is `xterm-256color`). Sadly, I also don’t like `ack` and it will take some configuration to get that to work how I want

Comment: New question posted: https://superuser.com/q/1709234/114723